# export inline var vs export var

Tags: c++, c++20

What is the difference between the two following declarations?

```
export module example;

export inline constexpr int i = 0;
```

```
export module example;

export constexpr int i = 0;
```

Or more generally:

```
export module example;

export inline int i;
```

```
export module example;

export int i;
```

Comment: In theory there's no difference. In reality g++ has trouble handling `export constexpr int i = 0;` while it's fine with `export inline constexpr int i = 0;`.

Comment: @cpplearner Both compiled fine on MSVC so if they're the same in theory then I'll stick with the short-hand.